# Why there is binary type after writing to hive table

Tags: python-2.7, hive

I read the data from oracle database to panda dataframe, then, there are some columns with type 'object', then I write the dataframe to hive table, these 'object' types are converted to 'binary' type, does any one know how to solve the problem?

Comment: try to cast 'object' to string or numeric types

Answer (score 0):

When you read data from oracle to dataframe it's created columns with object datatypes.

You can ask pandas dataframe try to infer better datatypes (before saving to Hive) if it can:
`dataframe.infer_objects()`